# 2D Matrix allocation on heap in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, memory-management, heap-memory

I am looking for a way to allocate a 2D (m *x* n) matrix on the heap where the elements are **consecutive** in memory. Currently I know of two ways to accomplish that:

#### First approach

```
int* M = new int[m * n];
```

- Pro: The size of `M` can by dynamically determined.
- Con: Indexing of `M` is a bit of a pain. (`M[i * m + j]`)

#### Second approach

```
typedef int dim[2];
dim* M = new dim[n];
```

- Pro: Indexing of `M` is just how I want it to be.
- Con: The size of the first dimension (m) cannot be set dynamically.

#### Question

Is there a way to allocate a 2D matrix dynamically on the heap where I can index the elements with `[i][j]` **and** the memory allocation is consecutive?

I know it would make a lot of sense to use a class for that, but I am specifically looking for a way as described above.

Comment: Sure, just write a custom `IntArray2D` class with an appropriate `operator[]` returning a proxy that overloads `operator[]` itself.

Comment: Hello Woltan, I would always use the first approach you mentioned. This might seem more awkward to work with the indices. But this is something you get used very fast. Save yourself the pain of having to work with the pointer stuff in the second approach and keep things simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this

```
int** M = new int*[m];
int *M_data = new int[m*n];

for(int i=0; i< m; ++i) 
{
    M[i] = M_data + i * n;
}
```

Comment: I like this answer the most because of its simplicity. All the conditions of the questions are met. (consecutive memory allocation and indexing)

Answer (score 4):

Here is a minimal version of the `IntArray2D` class I mentioned in my comment:

```
class IntArray2D
{
    std::vector<int> data_;
    int height_;
    int width_;

public:

    IntArray2D(int height, int width)
    : data_(height * width), height_(height), width_(width) 
    {
    }

    int* operator[](int index)
    {
        return &data_[index * width_];
    }

    const int* operator[](int index) const
    {
        return &data_[index * width_];
    }
};
```

Example usage:

```
IntArray2D test(100, 10);
test[99][9] = 42;
int i = test[0][0];
```

You may want to add bounds checking, and to do that in both dimensions, you need to return an appropriate proxy object instead of a pointer. Exercise left to the reader ;-)

Answer (score 2):

NOTE: see the edit below for ways to do it. I will keep the original post as is.

#### Original post

To make both sizes dynamic AND the elements consecutive, **you have no other way than your first method**. (**note**: see the edit, there are ways to do it, but with g++)

Think of it this way: When you tell the compiler to compute array[i][j], it would automatically translate it to either:

```
*(array+i*m+j)
```

if the array is static and `m` (the number of columns) is known. Or if the array is 2D (of type `type **`):

```
*(*(array+i)+j)
```

The second case is how you would do it normally with 2D arrays, but the data are NOT consecutive. That leaves you with the first option. Now in the first option, at compile time, the compiler **has to know** `m`. If you want `m` to be set at runtime, the compiler just can't compute `i*m+j`.

Now there are ways to work around this. One is the use of classes as you mentioned, which wraps around the `array = new type[n*m];` and overloads the `[]` operator properly. Another way to do it, which would require more memory (and thus I personally don't recommend) is to take a second array of type `type **` and instead of setting each element to a `new type[m]`, you set it to the beginning of rows in your one dimensional array.

Nonetheless, bottom line is, somewhere you **have to** have `new type[n*m]`

#### Edit: methods to do it, using g++

This emerged from the comments below:

```
type *array_helper = new type[n*m];
type (*array)[m] = (type (*)[m])array_helper;
```

Then you can use array and the elements are consecutive.

I also tried this, and it worked

```
type array[n][m];
```

and I printed the addresses, specifically checked `array[i][m-1]` and `array[i+1][0]` and the addresses are consecutive.

Comment: In modern C++, you very rarely **have to** have `new` anywhere in your own code.

Comment: Or you could cast the result of `new[m*n]` to an `(int(*)[m])`, and have the best of both worlds. You're underestimating compilers.

Comment: @Dave, That's exactly the same as writing OP's second method. The problem is `m` is set dynamically (it's not a constant) and therefore `(int *[m])` is not possible!

Comment: That's entirely false. I wrote a sample program http://pastebin.com/SMFRUM0c, which does exactly what OP wants. It compiles without warning on g++.

Comment: @Dave, I just tried with my g++ and I get an error. Are you sure you actually made `m` dynamic? Try this code:  `int m, n;
 cin >> n >> m;
 int *arr = new int[n*m];
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
   arr[i*m+j] = i*m+j;
 int **arr2 = (int (*)[m])arr;
 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j)
   cout << arr2[i][j] << endl;` For me, this doesn't compile and gives this error: `cannot convert 'int (*)[(((unsigned int)(((int)m) + -0x000000001)) + 1)]' to 'int**' in initialization`

Comment: It's fundamentally not an int**. It's a pointer to an array. Your error is because you erroneously attempted to assign a pointer-to-pointer a pointer-to-array. With my exact sample code, you should get no error.

Comment: Had you declared arr2 as `int (*arr2)[m]` rather than `int **arr` it would have compiled.

Comment: @Dave, you are right, with `int (*arr2)[m]` it works. I tried with `-std=c++98` it also worked.

Comment: @Dave, you know I had seen that with g++, you could just write `int arr[n*m]` and it would automatically allocate the memory, but I always that that's a g++ extension and not standard c++. Seems like it is standard. I would edit my post and add your solution.

Comment: @Woltan you might wanna take a look at the last lines of the edit.

Comment: @Dave, I tried with simply defining `int array[n][m]` and it actually worked (elements are also consecutive)

Comment: That's not quite the same as using `new`. That's actually allocation on the stack. Once `arr` goes out of scope, it's gone. I checked with `-pedantic`, and technically my approach is non-standard.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think it was until you brought up dynamic stack-based arrays, which I knew was a gnu extension.

Answer (score 1):

You want a pointer-to-(int-array):

```
 cin >> w >> h;
 int (*data)[w] = (int (*)[w])new int[w*h];
 for(int y=0;y<h;y++)
 for(int x=0;x<w;x++)
     data[y][x] = (w*y)+x;
```

Answer (score 1):

Building off crazyjul's answer you can do it with just one memory allocation.

```
int **arr = new int*[col*(row+1)];
for(int a=0; c<col; ++a){
    arr[a] = (int*)&arr[(a+1)*row];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C-like pseudocode:

```
int** M = new int*[m];
for(int i in 0..m-1) {
    M[i] = new int[n];
}
```

Comment: @crazyjul, oops, right. It seems to me, that one have to choice between memory consistency and indexing method

Answer (score 0):

Use boost [`array`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/array.html), [`matrix`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) or STL [`vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9xd04bzs.aspx)?

One more thing for your matrix: [*Why shouldn't my Matrix class's interface look like an array-of-array?*](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.11)